# Adding metadata to a node through a module

Tags: 7, nodes

I am developing a module that sync selected nodes with an outside site (another API on the web).  I need to add some meta-data to each node:

- Last sync time (timestamp) - Not editable through UI
- Outside API ID for this item - Not editable through UI
- Sync enabled for this node (yes/no) - Editable through UI

Should I have my module create a new table through the Drupal Database API to store this data, or should I use the Field API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirement seems pretty straight forward. If you want to save some time, I would suggest that you use the Field API. To make those fields non-editable by users and administrators, all you need to do is implement a [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and hide the form elements. You can also implement [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7), which I find more efficient.

Example. Hide the author field:

`$form['author']['#access'] = FALSE;`